# ubuntu install what do i do

Tags: system-installation, windows-7

I downloaded ubuntu 14 version for desktop from this site and after that absolutely nothing happened. I am new and lost. I don't see anything. I am using windows 7. This was 998 MB or so and it took an hour downloading

Comment: Taking your post literally, you seem to be saying that you cannot find the file that was downloaded - it this the case?

Comment: Did you click on some link, downloaded a file (likely named something like `ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso`) and you're wondering what to do next? Otherwise, please tell us more.

Answer (score 1):

After you download the ISO you need to make a bootable disk by using a DVD. But before you do that make sure you download an ISO reader at: http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/ You want to use this software to get the ISO onto the blank DVD. Here is the site that will take you step by step on how to usee ISO recorder to get the ISO you downloaded on your blank dvd: http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/HowTo.htm. Once you have the DVD ready put it in your CD/DVD drive and then shut down the computer. Once the computer is shut down, turn the computer back on and it should take you to an Ubuntu screen that will go through steps and it will ask you Do you want to erase your previous operating system, which Ubuntu will become your operating system. There are other questions it will ask you and then it will install. I hope this helps you install the operating system.